# Having an error code C2676 with an iterator to a vector of customtype

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

```cpp
vector<element>::iterator it;
it = find(table.begin(), table.end(), temp->c);
if (it != table.end()) {
    table.push_back(*temp);
}
```

That's where the error occurs

```cpp
struct element {
    char c;
    int freq;
    int first_index;
    struct element* next;
};

vector<element> table;
```

That's the declaration of the element struct and the vector.

I need to check whether or not the element is in the vector, if not push it back. Why doesn't it work? How could I fix it?

Here's the error code:

> Error C2676 binary '==': 'element' does not define 'element' that can be converted to an acceptable type for this operator or predefined operator

Comment: Please post the compiler error messages as well.

Comment: I updated  the post

Comment: Wouldn't you want to compare if the iterator is `== end()` if you want to add to the vector if the element doesn't exist?

Comment: What is `temp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `std::find_if()`, not `std::find()`.

The reason why [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) will not work is that `std::find` requires that the types in your vector can be comparable using `==` to the value you are searching for.  Since you're only searching for a `char` type, but the type in the `vector` is an`element`, you cannot compare an `element` to a `char` using `==` (unless you have an overloaded `operator ==` defined for the `element` class).

The function `std::find_if` allows you to specify how you want the comparison to be done, since it does not use `==` for the comparison.  For the comparison, you would supply a predicate function that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the item that is being tested is "equal".

For example, assuming that `temp` is an `element *`, we can use a lambda for the comparison function:

```
#include <algorithm>
//…
void foo()
{
    element* temp;
    //...
    auto it = std::find_if(table.begin(), table.end(), 
                       // comparison is done here   
                       [&](const element& e) {return e.c == temp->c;});

    if (it == table.end()) 
    {
       // element did not exist
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::find()` compares the input value to every item in the collection.  You are passing in a single `char`, but you don't have an `operator==` defined that can compare an entire `element` to a single `char`.  That is what the error message is complaining about.

Since you want to compare a specific field of the `element` struct, you need to use `std::find_if()` instead of `std::find()`.

Also, `std::find(_if)()` returns the `end` iterator if the requested item is not found.  Since you want to `push_back()` a new item if it is NOT found in the vector, you need to compare the returned iterator to the `end` iterator using `operator==`, not `operator!=`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
vector<element>::iterator it;
it = find_if(table.begin(), table.end(),
    [temp](const element &elem){ return elem.c == temp->c; }
);
if (it == table.end()) {
    table.push_back(*temp);
}
```